# Garbage collection: how is Eden space (and the other generation sizes) calculated?

Tags: java, solr, garbage-collection

I need help understanding how the GC-related numbers I'm getting from `jmap` and `jstat` relate to the settings I'm passing to java.  I'm starting the app (solr) with the following settings on a sever with 16GB of memory:

```
-XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled 
-Xms12144m -Xmx12144m 
-XX:NewRatio=4 -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

The output of `jmap` begins:

```
Concurrent Mark-Sweep GC

Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio = 40
   MaxHeapFreeRatio = 70
   MaxHeapSize      = 12733906944 (12144.0MB)
   NewSize          = 2686976 (2.5625MB)
   MaxNewSize       = 130809856 (124.75MB)
   OldSize          = 5439488 (5.1875MB)
   NewRatio         = 4
   SurvivorRatio    = 8
   PermSize         = 21757952 (20.75MB)
   MaxPermSize      = 176160768 (168.0MB)
```

Why are `NewSize`, `MaxNewSize`, `OldSize`, and `PermSize` all so small, when the `MaxHeapSize` is large?  Shouldn't `NewSize + OldSize = heap size`? And shouldn't the overall heap size be approaching `MaxHeapSize`?  Why is `NewSize` exactly half of `OldSize` when the `NewRatio` is set to 4?

The rest of the `jmap` output is below.  It matches the above, and includes a section `concurrent mark-sweep generation` which I also don't know how to interpret.

Additionally, the GC logs indicate that the "desired survivor size" is 6.2MB, which is also strange given I understand `-XX:SurvivorRatio=8` should make the survivor space 1/8 of `NewSize`.

Finally, I only ever see `ParNew` messages in my GC log, which I understand is the GC for Eden.

```
Heap Usage:
New Generation (Eden + 1 Survivor Space):
   capacity = 117768192 (112.3125MB)
   used     = 20402232 (19.45708465576172MB)
   free     = 97365960 (92.85541534423828MB)
   17.324059793666528% used
Eden Space:
   capacity = 104726528 (99.875MB)
   used     = 16408336 (15.648208618164062MB)
   free     = 88318192 (84.22679138183594MB)
   15.667793359863893% used
From Space:
   capacity = 13041664 (12.4375MB)
   used     = 3993896 (3.8088760375976562MB)
   free     = 9047768 (8.628623962402344MB)
   30.624128945508794% used
To Space:
   capacity = 13041664 (12.4375MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 13041664 (12.4375MB)
   0.0% used
concurrent mark-sweep generation:
   capacity = 12603097088 (12019.25MB)
   used     = 7903352408 (7537.22420501709MB)
   free     = 4699744680 (4482.02579498291MB)
   62.70960505037411% used
Perm Generation:
   capacity = 45903872 (43.77734375MB)
   used     = 27759192 (26.473228454589844MB)
   free     = 18144680 (17.304115295410156MB)
   60.472441191889% used
```

Answer (score 3):

> Why are NewSize, MaxNewSize, OldSize, and PermSize all so small, when the MaxHeapSize is large?

The sizes are only as large as they need to be.  The NewSize will be larger if you generate more short lived garbage (I don't know how the MaxNewSize is set, but its usually smaller than what I set it to)

> concurrent mark-sweep generation

This has the `capacity` = maximum size, `used` = used, `free` = capacity - used.

> ParNew messages in my GC log, which I understand is the GC for Eden.

As you noted, the new space is small so it cleans up often and the old gen is large so it cleans up rarely if at all.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the settings: if I start the app without the `NewRatio` and `SurvivorRatio` settings, the `NewSize` et al actually *increase* in size.  So an upper bound on `NewSize` is apparently being set by this variable. I assumed it wasn't dynamically allocating sizes (is that what you're saying?), because `NewSize` doesn't change over time.  

And regarding `concurrent mark-sweep generation` -- the size of `used` is shown as 7537MB, which should presumably equal new plus old.  But the output above says `OldSize` is 5.2MB.  None of these number appear to add up & I am still confused!

Comment: CMS only cleans the old gen so the new gen is not included and 4699744680 + 7903352408 = 12603097088 which adds up just fine. ;) You appear to be comparing numbers taken at different time (the first with the second)  They can change over time.

Comment: No, these numbers were all from the same `jmap` output. The first set is the Heap Configuration` part of the output and the second set is the `Heap Usage` part. I am confused about (a) the relationship between the numbers in the latter part and the former part, and(b) the relationship between the ratio numbers and the actual numbers in the former part. Something I hadn't realised but is now clearer is that the section labelled `concurrent mark-sweep generation` is what is elsewhere called `tenured` - right?

Comment: tenured space is a generic term across collectors. I expect the `concurrent mark-sweep generation` only applies when you are using the CMS.  I suspect you need to run the metric collection again making sure you are collecting data at the same time. e.g is `jmap` perfoming a full collection before taking the dump so only live objects are stored.  The numbers can decrease dramatically is a fraction second. I suggest you use visualvm to monitor the heap spaces while you do this to ensure you are not disturbing the heap my monitoring it. BTW Using visualvm disturbs the heap as well.

Comment: Great, thanks, will do. I've also found, however, that `NewRatio` behaves in an odd and possibly buggy way when using CMS.  I've got much more understandable relationships between the `Heap Configuration` and the `Heap Usage` when setting an explicit `NewSize` with `-XX:NewSize=2g`.